# "Sorry, something went wrong" Can't access SharePoint Portals as an admin

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, site-collection

Everything was working fine and suddenly, I can't access SharePoint Sever 2013 portals that I created, I got that error :

[image]

I checked the ULS log, but I couldn't understand the cause of the error.

```
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 04/29/2016 09:05:51.77, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion: {0}   b247779d-a62e-506e-4079-26a0cc01a110
04/29/2016 09:05:51.81  w3wp.exe (0x48D0)                           0x63CC  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                agyfw   Unexpected  Unexpected error occurred in method 'Put' , usage 'SPViewStateCache' - Exception 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0018>:SubStatus<ES0001>:The request timed out.. Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server : net.tcp://TGCWSSPDEV01.thegundcompany.local:22233     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody, RequestBody reqBody)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalPut(String key, Object value, DataCacheItemVersion oldVersion, TimeSpan timeout, DataCacheTag[] tags, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.<>c__DisplayClass25.<Put>b__24()     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.Put(String... b247779d-a62e-506e-4079-26a0cc01a110
04/29/2016 09:05:51.81* w3wp.exe (0x48D0)                           0x63CC  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                agyfw   Unexpected  ... key, Object value, TimeSpan timeout)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache.Put(String key, Object value)'.  b247779d-a62e-506e-4079-26a0cc01a110
04/29/2016 09:05:51.82  w3wp.exe (0x48D0)                           0x63CC  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajb4s   Monitorable ViewStateLog: Failed to write to the velocity cache: http :// tgcwsspdev01:46145/sites/My Storage Information/SitePages/Home.aspx   b247779d-a62e-506e-4079-26a0cc01a110
```

[image]

Can any one help me!

Answer (score 1):

Can you get to Central Admin? Can you try to create a new site collection? How about PowerShell? Try to see if your Distributed Cache is up and running.

Here is a good msdn article about troubleshooting your Distributed Cache. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2014/03/19/sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-appfabric-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I checked the SharePoint Management Shell as an administrator, the local Farm was nos accessible. Now the problem is resolved, I just restarted the server. But when I open the  task manager, I can see a process that is running with big memory " DistributedCacheService" . Do you have any idea? Can I stop it ?

Comment: Distributed Cache service should take 10 percent of the total physical memory on the server. Can you check that first? and you can check the allocation with the following PS command:

Use-CacheCluster Get-AFCacheHostConfiguration -ComputerName ComputerName -CachePort "22233"

or if you want to updat it, use the following:
Update-SPDistributedCacheSize -CacheSizeInMB CacheSize

I don't know much about how your environment is configured, but I don't recommend to stop this service!